# (X)Ubuntu 14.04 LTS completely freezes on my Alienware 14

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, xfce, xorg-edgers

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (and Xubuntu 14.04 LTS afterward) on my Alienware 14 (specs below) in dual boot with Windows 8.1 x64. I'm experiencing random and sporadic freezes (the mouse is not responding, the desktop environment is frozen, Ctrl + Alt + F1 [...F2, F3...] or other key combinations are not doing anything). In some cases, after a long delay, the system unfreezes and I'm able to continue, but in most cases, I have to reboot (pressing the Power button on my laptop for several seconds). I can reproduce this problem consistently while using Rviz + Gazebo (3D simulation applications from [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz) environment) for more than 1 or 2 minutes. I suspect it's related to graphic drivers.

I installed (and selected through "Additional drivers" interface) the nvidia-331-updates drivers (actually, I had to boot in "safe mode" (resume) to select this specific driver, I was not able to boot the regular). I even tried with xorg-edgers drivers but it didn't make any difference (maybe I'm doing it wrong ?)

I'm a new Ubuntu user, I tried to search within the logs for more information on this issue, but I don't even what (and where) I'm looking for. At this point, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Alienware 14 (Dell)
Intel Core i7 4900MQ @ 2.80GHz
16,0 Go Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 798 MHz
Intel HD Graphics 4600 (Dell)
2047 MoNVIDIA GeForce GTX 765M (Dell)
```